# Trouble reading a specific file

Tags: c

I want to read a file that in code I'm naming `fpr2`
The format of the file is the following:

```
#ROUTE 1
America
Canada
Portugal

#ROUTE 2
Portugal
Brazil
```

I want to make it read *in sections*, read the 1st route, do operations and then read the 2nd route, with the option of adding more routes later in the file I'm reading.

```
    ler_rotas(FILE* fpr2, int route) {
    char* vret;
    char vlinha[DIM];
    vlinha[0]= '\0';
    int nc;

    char hashtag[DIM];
    int number;

    char base[DIM];

    int nbloco=1;

    nc = fscanf(fpr2, "%s %d", hashtag, &number);
    if(route==1){
    printf("%s %d\n", hashtag, number);}
/*this part above reads the #ROUTE 1  (in other routes the number is going to be different) */

    do {
            if(nbloco==1){
    vret = fgets(vlinha,DIM, fpr2);

    nc=fscanf(fpr2, "%s", base);
    if(strcmp(base,"#ROUTE")!=0){printf("%s\n",base);}

    if(strcmp(base,"#ROUTE")==0) {
        nbloco+=1;
    }
            }
/*this part above scans and prints untill it finds the next #ROUTE, simbolizing the end of this
particular bloco */

/*now this is the part with errors (below)*/

    if(nbloco!=1) {
        vret = fgets(vlinha,DIM, fpr2);
        printf("\n");
        nc = fscanf(fpr2, "%s %d", hashtag, &number);
        printf("%s %d\n", hashtag, number);
        return ;
    }

    }while(vret!=NULL);
}
```

The output is the following

```
#ROUTE 1
America
Canada
Portugal

Portugal 1
```

As you can see it isn't outputting the 2nd block correctly.

Comment: Read the file line by line with `fgets()` and then you can examine what each line might contain.

Comment: Are the routes always separated by a `'#'`?

Comment: Yes the routes are always separated by `'#'`

Comment: Don't mix the use of `fscanf` with `fgets`. Use one or the other.

Comment: @TiagoCastro Are the routes always separated by an empty line?

Comment: @Zakk yes they are

Comment: @TiagoCastro Just to clarify things more: Do you aim to read _only_ the block given in `route` parameter? Or you aim to read _everything up to_ the block given in `route`?

Comment: Tiago Castro, What is `DIM`?

Comment: ok so i fixed it

Answer (score 0):

Fixed code

```
ler_rotas(FILE* fpr2, int rota)
{
    char tag[DIM];
    char base[DIM];
    int numero=0;
    int read;
    int nc;
    printf("rota de momento = %d\n", rota);
    if (rota==0)
    {
        read=0;
        nc = fscanf(fpr2, "%s %d", tag, &numero);
        do{
        nc= fscanf(fpr2, "%s", base);

        if(strcmp(base,"#ROTA")==0)
        {
            read=1;
            strcpy(base, "");
            nc=fscanf(fpr2, "%d", &numero);
        }
        if(nc!=-1){printf("%s\n",base);}
        }while(nc!=-1);
    }

    if (rota!=0)
    {

        do{

        if(numero==rota)
        {
            //printf("numero=rota\n");
            nc= fscanf(fpr2, "%s", base);
            if(strcmp(base,"#ROTA")==0)
            {
                return;
            }
        if(nc!=-1){printf("%s\n",base);}
        }

        if(numero!=rota)
        {
            nc=fscanf(fpr2, "%s %d",tag, &numero);
            //printf("numeor %d\n",numero);
        }


        }while(nc!=-1);
    }


}
```

Comment: `fscanf(fpr2, "%s %d", tag, &numero);` without a _width_ in `"%s"` is weak code.